# solo se ejecuta la ultima instancia de settimeout

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente tabla vacía:

```js
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById("atras").disabled=true; //se desactiva el boton al pulsar guardar
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("atras").disabled=false; // después de 5 segundos el boton se vuelve a activar
        }, 5000);
        const pregunta = document.getElementById('preg').value; //valor del campo pregunta
        const verdadero = document.getElementById('v').checked; //valor del campo verdadero
        const falso = document.getElementById('f').checked; //valor del campo falso
        const puntaje = parseInt(document.getElementById('punt').value); //valor del campo puntuacion, lo tranformamos en string
        let resultado = document.getElementById('regpre');
        let count = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let control = true;
        let respuesta;
        if (verdadero == true) {
            respuesta = 'Verdadero';
        } else if (falso == true) {
            respuesta = 'Falso';
            control = false;
        }
        let resp = {
            'nombre': pregunta,
            'respuesta': control,
            'puntuacion': puntaje,
            'estado' : 'Ok'
        }
        //Actualizar Usuario Actual cookies
        const namepreg = 'preg'+count;
        let rows = '<tr><td>'+pregunta+'</td><td>'+respuesta+'</td><td>'+puntaje+'</td><td id="'+namepreg+'">Cargando...</td></tr>';
        window.pintarHtml(resultado,rows).then(function (result) {
            window.updatestatus(namepreg);
        });
});
    
function updatestatus(namepreg){
    const last_td = document.getElementById(namepreg);
    if(last_td.innerText=='Cargando...'){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Llegue hasta aqui');
            last_td.innerText = 'Ok';
        }, 5000);
    }
}

function pintarHtml(resultado,rows){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(resultado.innerHTML += rows);
    });
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left">
<form id ="miFormulario" method="post">
        <label for="pregunta">Pregunta</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="preg" required/>
        <div id="radio">
          <input type="radio" id="v" name="booleano" value="verdadero" />
          <label for="v">Verdadero</label>
          <input type="radio" id="f" name="booleano" value="falso" />
          <label for="f">Falso</label>
        </div>
        <label for="puntuacion">Puntuacion</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="punt" min="1" max="9" required />
        <div id="botones">
          <input type="button" value="Atras" id="atras"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Grabar" id="enviar"/>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px">
<table id="respuestas" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Pregunta</th>
            <th>Respuesta</th>
            <th>Puntuacion</th>
            <th>------Estado------</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="regpre">
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

mediante un botón le agrego Filas... y se supone que cuando he agregado la fila busco el ultimo TD, la idea es agregarle a este `TD` un `setTimeout` que pasado 5 segundo cambie el texto.

```
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //inserto un tr al final
        //obtengo el ultimo TD de la tabla;
        //llamo a la funcion que agrega el setTimeout
});

function updatestatus(namepreg){
    let last_td = document.getElementById(namepreg);
    if(last_td.innerText=='Cargando...'){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Llegue hasta aqui');
            last_td.innerText = 'Ok';
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

pero al final si doy varios click que vayan agregando lineas por algun motivo el los setTimeout previos no se cumplen/terminan de ejecutar; solo el ultimo y quedo con esto tengo esto:

```html
<div>
<table id="respuestas" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Pregunta</th>
            <th>Respuesta</th>
            <th>Puntuacion</th>
            <th>------Estado------</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="regpre">
          <tr><td>8</td><td>Falso</td><td>5</td><td id="preg7">Cargando...</td></tr>
          <tr><td>9</td><td>Falso</td><td>5</td><td id="preg8">ok...</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

se supone que deben ejecutarce uno a uno hasta llegar al final... alguna idea que esta mal???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con las promesas debes evitar el uso de variables globales, porque se van a actualizar cada que se ejecute la función y el resultado será inesperado. Es necesario limitar las variables al contexto de la promesa para que el comportamiento sea el adecuado.

Revisa los comentarios para saber dónde se hicieron las correcciones.

```js
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById("atras").disabled=true; //se desactiva el boton al pulsar guardar
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("atras").disabled=false; // después de 5 segundos el boton se vuelve a activar
        }, 5000);
        const pregunta = document.getElementById('preg').value; //valor del campo pregunta
        const verdadero = document.getElementById('v').checked; //valor del campo verdadero
        const falso = document.getElementById('f').checked; //valor del campo falso
        const puntaje = parseInt(document.getElementById('punt').value); //valor del campo puntuacion, lo tranformamos en string
        let resultado = document.getElementById('regpre');
        let count = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let control = true;
        let respuesta;
        if (verdadero == true) {
            respuesta = 'Verdadero';
        } else if (falso == true) {
            respuesta = 'Falso';
            control = false;
        }
        let resp = {
            'nombre': pregunta,
            'respuesta': control,
            'puntuacion': puntaje,
            'estado' : 'Ok'
        }
        // Enviar parámetros a función para evitar usar variables globales
        window.pintarHtml(pregunta, respuesta, puntaje, count).then(function (result) {
            // Debes realizar los cambios dentro de la promesa
            // Obteniendo datos de propiedades del objeto result
            resultado.innerHTML += result.html;
            let last_td = document.getElementById(result.namepreg);
            if(last_td.innerText=='Cargando...'){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Se debe obtener nuevamente el elemento, basado en result.namepreg
                    // Evitando usar la misma variable creada en el paso anterior
                    let last_td = document.getElementById(result.namepreg);
                    console.log('Llegue hasta aqui');
                    last_td.innerText = 'Ok';
                }, 5000);
            }
      });
});

// Recibir parámetros para crear contenido y resolver la promesa
function pintarHtml(pregunta, respuesta, puntaje, count){
    //Actualizar Usuario Actual cookies
    const namepreg = 'preg'+count;
    let rows = '<tr><td>'+pregunta+'</td><td>'+respuesta+'</td><td>'+puntaje+'</td><td id="'+namepreg+'">Cargando...</td></tr>';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Devolver un objeto con contenido HTML e id de celda
        resolve({html: rows, namepreg: namepreg});
    });
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left">
<form id ="miFormulario" method="post">
        <label for="pregunta">Pregunta</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="preg" required/>
        <div id="radio">
          <input type="radio" id="v" name="booleano" value="verdadero" />
          <label for="v">Verdadero</label>
          <input type="radio" id="f" name="booleano" value="falso" />
          <label for="f">Falso</label>
        </div>
        <label for="puntuacion">Puntuacion</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="punt" min="1" max="9" required />
        <div id="botones">
          <input type="button" value="Atras" id="atras"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Grabar" id="enviar"/>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px">
<table id="respuestas" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Pregunta</th>
            <th>Respuesta</th>
            <th>Puntuacion</th>
            <th>------Estado------</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="regpre">
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```